# translate delimited text symfony2

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

I am needing translate parts of a text (in twig).

Something like that:

```
// page.html.twig

    ...
    {{ text | trans ({}, 'MyprojectMyBundle')}}
```

Supos variable 'text' have the string: "Value is between 5 and 10"

In translation arquive I have:

```
// Project/MyBundle/Resources/Translations/MyprojectMyBundle.pt_BR.yml

...
Value is between and : "Valor está entre e"
```

How can I escape the numbers (5 and 10) in translation?
I need:

Value is between 5 and 10 -> Valor está entre 5 e 10

Value is between 50 and 60 -> Valor está entre 50 e 60

etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use placeholders, so in your translation file you would have:

```
// Project/MyBundle/Resources/Translations/MyprojectMyBundle.pt_BR.yml

...
Value is between %min% and %max%: "Valor está entre %min% e %max%"
```

and then in your template you can use the following:

```
{{ text | trans({'%min%': '5', '%max%': '10'}, "MyprojectMyBundle") }}
```

where text = 'Value is between %min% and %max%'

Comment: but min and max will change every time

Comment: Yes, you can replace the '5' & '10' with template variables which contain the values, eg {{ text | trans({'%min%': minval, '%max%': maxval}, "MyprojectMyBundle") }}

Comment: Works! But 'text' now is a array with ('text', 'min', 'max). So I can call {{ text.text | trans({'%min%': 'text.min', '%max%': 'text.max'}, "MyprojectMyBundle") }}
Thx!

Comment: awesomeness! glad to be of assistance